# Stretch div to bottom of screensize, but allow scrolldown

Tags: css, position

On load I'd like to load the **topsection** div with a bg image and have it take up the entire screen, but then I have content below it which you can scroll down to. The div should size itself to the window screen only on load and not remain like that on scrolldown. I cannot give the div a position:absolute; either.

I'm banging my head on this one. I've tried a ton of different things

Here is my html:

```
 <div id="topsection" class="row bgimage ">

<div id="logomain" class="mainlogo ">
    <div class=" floorplanbuttoncontainer helvetical">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="floorplanbutton my_popup_open">Residence A - Duplex</a></li>
         <li>
         <a href="javascript:;" class="floorplanbutton my_popup3_open">Residence D - Simplex</a></li>

        </ul>       
     </div><!-- end floorplanbuttoncontainer -->

     </div><!-- end logomain -->
```

Here is my css for the background image:

```
  .bgimage {
     background: url(images/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
     background-size: cover;


  .mainlogo {
     margin:0 auto;text-align:center;width:100%;height:488px; /*I think this height is messing things up */
      background-image:url(images/picture.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
      }
```

Comment: Your `.bgimage` is never closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Modern browsers:** a simple way is to use `vh` units to get the *Viewport Height*

Just to simplify: [***jsBin demo***](http://jsbin.com/nepuvi/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<div id="home" class="container full">
    <h1>HOME</h1>
</div>
<div id="about" class="container">
    <h1>About us</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { min-height:400px; }
.full { height:100vh; }
```

**Crossbrowser:** use `%` instead of `vh` and simply add `html, body{height:100%;}` ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/nepuvi/3/edit)***

Answer (score 1):

In order to set a `div` to take up the entire screen you need to set the height of the `body` and `html` element to `100%`. You also have to remove the `padding` and `margin` from them. Then you create a wrapper class to encase your content and assign it your `background-image`. Then all ya' gotta do is create the content below your full screen image to scroll into!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/femxh3Lk/)

### Edit

If you run the snippet below and hit full page you can see how it works.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.full {
    width: 100%;
}
.footerThing {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="full">
        asd
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footerThing">
    
</div>
```